Adding a new "Book" object created in Form2 to List<Book> created by an "Import" object in Form1
I am new to Windows Forms and my assignment is to create a program that upon launch, populates a list of books from a txt file and then allow the user to click a button and display a random book as a suggestion of what to read. This is all working as intended.
My problem is that I want to be able to click a button, open a 2nd form which then allows the user to add a new book to both the List and the txt file. I have successfully made the new Book object add to the txt file and upon closing and relaunching the program, the new book shows up when I display random books but I am having trouble adding it to List books. The list has to be created by an object of the class "Import" but I cant figure out how to pass import into Form2 to be able to access the List when adding the new Book.
Classes.cs
namespace Tipsmaskinen
{
    internal class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string BookType { get; set; }
        public bool Available = false;

        public Book(string title, string author)
        {
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (Available)
            {
                return Title + " av " + Author + Environment.NewLine + "(" + BookType + ")" + Environment.NewLine + "Boken finns tillgänglig!";
            }
            else
            {
                return Title + " av " + Author + Environment.NewLine + "(" + BookType + ")" + Environment.NewLine + "Boken är tyvärr inte tillgänglig!";
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Novel : Book
    {
        public Novel(string title, string author)
            : base(title, author)
        {
            BookType = "Roman";
        }
    }

    internal class Magazine : Book
    {
        public Magazine(string title, string author)
            : base(title, author)
        {
            BookType = "Tidskrift";
        }
    }

    internal class ShortStories : Book
    {
        internal ShortStories(string title, string author)
            : base(title, author)
        {
            BookType = "Novellsamling";
        }
    }

    internal class Import
    {
        public List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        public void FileLoader()
        {
            List<string> itemSaver = new List<string>();
            if (File.Exists("library.txt"))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("library.txt", Encoding.UTF8, false);
                string item = "";
                while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    itemSaver.Add(item);
                }
                foreach (string a in itemSaver)
                {
                    string[] vektor = a.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    if (vektor[2] == "Roman")
                    {
                        Novel newNovel = new Novel(vektor[0], vektor[1]);
                        if (vektor[3] == "true")
                        {
                            newNovel.Available = true;
                        }
                        if (newNovel.Title != null && newNovel.Author != null)
                        {
                            books.Add(newNovel);
                        }
                        
                    }
                    if (vektor[2] == "Tidskrift")
                    {
                        Magazine newMagazine = new Magazine(vektor[0], vektor[1]);
                        if (vektor[3] == "true")
                        {
                            newMagazine.Available = true;
                        }
                        if (newMagazine.Title != null && newMagazine.Author != null)
                        {
                            books.Add(newMagazine);
                        }
                    }
                    if (vektor[2] == "Novellsamling")
                    {
                        ShortStories newShorts = new ShortStories(vektor[0], vektor[1]);
                        if (vektor[3] == "true")
                        {
                            newShorts.Available = true;
                        }
                        if (newShorts.Title != null && newShorts.Author != null)
                        {
                            books.Add(newShorts);
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create("library.txt"))
                MessageBox.Show("library.txt hittades inte och har skapats!");
            }
            
        }
    }
}

Form1.cs
namespace Tipsmaskinen
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Import import = new Import();
        public Random rnd = new Random();
        public int lastResult;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            import.FileLoader();
        }

        private void SuggestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            bool repeat = true;
            while(repeat)
            {
                int result = rnd.Next(0, import.books.Count);
                if (result != lastResult)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = import.books[result].ToString();
                    repeat = false;
                    lastResult = result;
                }
            }
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}


Form2.cs
namespace Tipsmaskinen
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (titleBox.Text != "" && authorBox.Text != "" && booktypeBox.Text != "")
            {
                Book newBook = new Book(titleBox.Text, authorBox.Text);
                newBook.BookType = booktypeBox.Text;
                newBook.Available = availableBox.Checked;
                import.books.Add(newBook);
                string newBookAvailable = "false";
                if (availableBox.Checked)
                {
                    newBookAvailable = "true";
                }
                string newBookExport = titleBox.Text + "###" + authorBox.Text + "###" + booktypeBox.Text + "###" + newBookAvailable;
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("library.txt", append: true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(newBookExport);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Boken tillagd!");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Titel, författare och boktyp är alla obligatoriska!");
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried adding import as a parameter to the method but this gave me an error with the event handler.

Note that a Form is just a class. So, you can do the same things with it as with other classes. Add a constructor to the second form having the the Import object as parameter:
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Import _import;

    public Form2(Import import)
    {
        _import = import;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ... // here you can use _import.books
}

Then create the form like this:
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2(import);
    form2.Show();
}

It is important to understand that classes are reference types. This means the you will only be passing a reference to the original object containing the books to Form2 and not a copy of it or of the books.
Many developers start field names with an underscore (_) to better distinguish them from variables and parameters.
_import can be made read-only because it will not be changed after initialization. You can still change its contents, i.e., the books it contains, at any time.

Another way you can do it is to define event on Form2 and handle it in parent form, like below:
// Define delegate to add book...
public delegate void BookAdding(
    string title,
    string author,
    string type,
    bool available);

public class Form2
{
    // ...and in Form2 define event that will be raised upon save button click.
    public event BookAdding BookAdding;
}

and then subscribe to event when showing the form:
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.BookAdding += OnBookAdding;
    form2.Show();
}

private void OnBookAdding(string title, string author, string type, bool available)
{
    // Create and save new book.
}


As I understand it, the purpose of Form2 is simply to collect the information to create a new book. Consider having Form2 do only that because there is no need for it to know anything about the Import class or really anything else. The benefit is that this greatly simplifies the input form and while your at it you can disable the [Save] button until the inputs are complete and valid.

    public enum BookType { Novel, Magazine, ShortStories, NonFiction,  }
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CancelButton = buttonCancel;
            AcceptButton = buttonSave;
            buttonSave.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            buttonSave.Enabled = false;
            textBoxTitle.PlaceholderText = "Title";
            textBoxAuthor.PlaceholderText = "Author";
            comboBoxBookType.Items.AddRange(
                Enum
                .GetValues(typeof(BookType))
                .OfType<object>()
                .ToArray());
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            // Validate to conditionally enable the Save button
            textBoxTitle.TextChanged += EnableSaveButtonIfValid;
            textBoxAuthor.TextChanged += EnableSaveButtonIfValid;
            comboBoxBookType.SelectionChangeCommitted += EnableSaveButtonIfValid;
        }

        private void EnableSaveButtonIfValid(object? sender, EventArgs e) =>
            buttonSave.Enabled = 
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BookTitle) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Author) &&
                BookType is BookType;

        protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
            if(Visible)
            {
                // Prevents the text box from obtaining focus 
                // so that the placeholder text remains visible.
                BeginInvoke(() => ActiveControl = null);
            }
        }
        public string BookTitle => textBoxTitle.Text;
        public string Author => textBoxAuthor.Text;
        public BookType? BookType => (BookType?)comboBoxBookType.SelectedItem;
        public bool Available => checkBoxAvailable.Checked;
    }


Making a new Form2 instance in the handler for buttonAdd_Click resets the placeholder text providing a "fresh start" every time the input form is shown to add a new book. The using block ensures proper disposal of the form handle when the dialog closes. Make sure to inspect the DialogResult of the ShowDialog method before leaving the using block, and if the operation hasn't been cancelled then the main form - which has everything it requires in terms of the list of books and the ability to save it - can proceed to do the heavy lifting without the need to subscribe to events or pass references.
Here's some example code for the ShowDialog call that retrieves the necessary properties to create a new book and adds it to the list in memory. You should be able to easily adapt this to use the Import class that you say is required by the assignment.
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Random rnd = new Random();
        public int? lastResult = null;
        public string JsonPath { get; } =
            Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Name!,
                "library.json");

        List<Book> Books;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            textBox1.PlaceholderText = "Click for Suggestion";
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox1.TabStop = false;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(JsonPath)!);
        }

        // using Newtonsoft.Json
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (File.Exists(JsonPath))
            {
                Books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(File.ReadAllText(JsonPath))!;
            }
            else
            {
                Books = new List<Book>();
            }
            switch (Books.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    buttonSuggest.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textBox1.Text = Books.Single().ToString();
                    buttonSuggest.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    buttonSuggest.Enabled = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var form2 = new Form2())
            {
                switch (form2.ShowDialog(this))
                {
                    case DialogResult.OK:
                        var book = new Book
                        {
                            Title = form2.BookTitle,
                            Author = form2.Author,
                            BookType = form2.BookType,
                            Available = form2.Available,
                        };
                        Books.Add(book);
                        textBox1.Text = book.ToString();
                        lastResult = Books.Count;
                        File.WriteAllText(JsonPath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Books, Formatting.Indented));
                        buttonSuggest.Enabled = Books.Count > 1;
                        break;
                    case DialogResult.Cancel:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonSuggest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Books.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textBox1.Text = Books.Single().ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int result = rnd.Next(0, Books.Count);
                        if (result != lastResult)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = Books[result].ToString();
                            lastResult = result;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

